# CSS3 animate not working locally

Tags: css

Hi,I am trying to replicate this code locally and on jsfiddle .Everything works except the animations. Could someone point out what is missing here so the animations work as well?

Original:
http://codepen.io/pixelgrid/pen/suflz

Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/FeZq9/

I believe it has something to do with animations property

```
@keyframes round{ 100%{ transform:rotate( 360deg ); } }
animation:round 9s linear infinite;
```

Thanks

Comment: Both appear the same to me.

Comment: You need to post your local code

Comment: Im on the latest version of chrome and the codepen code is animating but jsfiddle isnt..

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5457819

Comment: I have checked the code on jsfiddle as well as on codeprn, both are working fine :). FYI i`m using firefox 17

Answer (score 0):

Try it with an other browser like Firefox or Oopera

Comment: Tried it on opera and firefox and safari. Only codepen version is animating the rest is stationary..

Comment: @user1850342: I have checked on firefox, its works fine , i hope your using latest version of browser, since some old versions wont support CSS3

Comment: it's not solution to upgrade YOUR browser or to change browser, what about all other users that still use old browsers and have only one browser? you cant say to clients please us only latest FF browser.

Answer (score 0):

check this one nothing is wrong just add browser prefix for all animation property.
codepen do it itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/FeZq9/1/

```
.cloud {
transform-origin:50% 400px;
  -webkit-transform-origin:50% 400px;
  -moz-transform-origin:50% 400px;
  -o-transform-origin:50% 400px;
  animation:round 7s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:round 7s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:round 7s linear infinite;
    -o-animation:round 7s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes round {
100%{ -webkit-transform:rotate( 360deg ); }
}

 @-moz-keyframes round { 
100%{ -moz-transform:rotate( 360deg ); }
}

 @-o-keyframes round { 

100%{ -o-transform:rotate( 360deg ); }
}
 @keyframes round { 
100%{ transform:rotate( 360deg ); }
}
```